# Other moveTo(x,y) canvas function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm searching for canvas function that would animate my shape to x,y position.
For example I have an array that holds all the shapes to draw, and I just "tell" to object "animate to x,y coordinate" like this:

```
// Array that holds all the shapes to draw
var shapes = new Array();

// Setting up some shapes
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var x = Math.random()*250;
    var y = Math.random()*250;
    var width = height = Math.random()*30;
    shapes.push(new Shape(x, y, width, height));
};

function animate() {
    // Clear
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // Loop through every object
    var shapesLength = shapes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < shapesLength; i++) {
        var tmpShape = shapes[i];

        //here should go function that would animate my shape to x,y postition
        var x = tmpShape.x????;
        var y = tmpShape.y????;

        // Draw
        context.fillRect(x, y, tmpShape.width, tmpShape.height);
    };

    setTimeout(animate, 33);
};
```

I haven't tried anything because i don't know how to do this at all.

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."*

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for adding your code.  We thrive by consuming code here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are moving from a starting to ending point along a line, you can calculate the XY at a specified percentage of that trip like this:

```
// pct goes from 0.00 to 1.00 as you go from the starting to ending points

var dx=endingX-startingX;
var dy=endingY-startingY;
var nextX=startingX+dx*pct;
var nextY=startingY+dy*pct;
```

Comment: what does mean specified percentage ?

Comment: So if pct=0.00 then you're at the starting point of the line segment. If pct=0.33 you're 1/3 from start to end.  If pct=1.00, you're at the ending point of the line segment.

Comment: Got it.
Btw I'm searching something like [this](http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html)  and [this](http://phrogz.net/svg/animation_on_a_curve.html), but for a straight line

Comment: Yes, this formula will navigate a straight line between any starting point [startingX,startingY] and any ending point [endingX, endingY] and you would "move" the shape by clearing the canvas and then context.fillRect(newX,newY,shape.width,shape.height)

Comment: To your last question: NO.  You want to increment pct from 0.00 to 1.00 in your animation loop to calculate XY along the line from start to end.